# Plasmashell stopped working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I'm using kubuntu 15.04. All of a sudden (without doing an upgrade), when I log in, my plasma does not start. I am in the desktop with my applications open, but no panels, no menu, no background.

sudo plasmashell works (but as a root), not as a normal user. I'll try upgrading now, but I'm a bit worried I should fix this first. Maybe I should check a particular log?

Could this be a permissions problem? I've been using Dolphin as a root to solve a backup problem's write permissions, maybe that was a bad idea.

--UPDATE

I changed the ownership of all files in /home/me to myself. Afterwards, trying to run plasmashell:

```
Crash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 2218
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell --crashes 2 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0

[1]+  Stopped                 plasmashell
dorien@XP:~$ clear
dorien@XP:~$ plasmashell
kf5.kiconthemes: "Theme tree: (Breeze)"
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_lookandfeel.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_wallpaper.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_share.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_layoutemplate.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_plasmashell.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_wallpaperimages.so" instead.
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/dorien/.cache/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open global ksycoca from  "/home/dorien/.local/share/kservices5/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/dorien/.cache/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open global ksycoca from  "/home/dorien/.local/share/kservices5/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Still no database...
No ksycoca database available! Tried running kbuildsycoca5 ?
KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "Plasma/Containment" not found
No ksycoca database available! Tried running kbuildsycoca5 ?
KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "Plasma/LayoutTemplate" not found
"file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/osd/Osd.qml" 
 "Error loading QML file.
21: module "org.kde.plasma.components" is not installed
22: module "org.kde.plasma.extras" is not installed
20: module "org.kde.plasma.core" is not installed
21: module "org.kde.plasma.components" is not installed
22: module "org.kde.plasma.extras" is not installed
20: module "org.kde.plasma.core" is not installed
21: module "org.kde.plasma.components" is not installed
22: module "org.kde.plasma.extras" is not installed
20: module "org.kde.plasma.core" is not installed
"
Application::crashHandler() called with signal 11; recent crashes: 1
/usr/bin/plasmashell  --crashes 1 &
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 2232
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
kf5.kiconthemes: "Theme tree: (Breeze)"
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_lookandfeel.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_wallpaper.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_share.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_layoutemplate.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_plasmashell.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_wallpaperimages.so" instead.
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/dorien/.cache/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open global ksycoca from  "/home/dorien/.local/share/kservices5/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open ksycoca from "/home/dorien/.cache/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Trying to open global ksycoca from  "/home/dorien/.local/share/kservices5/ksycoca5"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Still no database...
No ksycoca database available! Tried running kbuildsycoca5 ?
KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "Plasma/Containment" not found
No ksycoca database available! Tried running kbuildsycoca5 ?
KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "Plasma/LayoutTemplate" not found
"file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/osd/Osd.qml" 
 "Error loading QML file.
20: module "org.kde.plasma.core" is not installed
21: module "org.kde.plasma.components" is not installed
22: module "org.kde.plasma.extras" is not installed
20: module "org.kde.plasma.core" is not installed
21: module "org.kde.plasma.components" is not installed
22: module "org.kde.plasma.extras" is not installed
20: module "org.kde.plasma.core" is not installed
21: module "org.kde.plasma.components" is not installed
22: module "org.kde.plasma.extras" is not installed
"
Application::crashHandler() called with signal 11; recent crashes: 2
/usr/bin/plasmashell  --crashes 2 &
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 2236
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell --crashes 1 
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0
kf5.kiconthemes: "Theme tree: (Breeze)"
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_lookandfeel.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_wallpaper.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_share.so" instead.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo
...
```

I did recently set my DL_LIBRARY_PATH variable in .bashrc. Could that be interfering? (looking at [this](https://community.kde.org/Frameworks/Building#Runtime_setup) bugreport)

-- UPDATE2

I've created a new user. Plasma works perfect for that user. It's a bit annoying to have to do all my desktop settings again, but ok...  I'm guessing it was a permission problem then? No clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a permissions problem. I've managed to open user manager (sudo plasmashell in the konsole that happened to be open (thank god) and the system settings). Creating a new user (and loggin in with that user) seemed to have solved it.

Afterwards I was stupid enough to do sudo chown -R me /home/me and it messed it up again! After 10 years of linux use I should have know this. The hidden file permissions are important...